# Generate fillable / editable PDF in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, dompdf, mpdf

I am generating **DOM PDF** in laravel using **barryvdh/laravel-dompdf** package. It is working fine by rendering the views and HTML elements with readonly mode. But, I am trying to generate fillable / editable PDF so that user can enter details with out opening it in 3rd party editor tools.

Below is the code snippet I am using to generate PDF with barryvdh/laravel-dompdf package.

```
    $file = "Storage/pdf/document.pdf";
    $data = array("foo" => "bar");
    $view = view('pdf.document', $data);
    \PDF::loadHTML($view)->setPaper('A4', 'portrait')->setWarnings(false)-save($file);
```

I have also tried mpdf **niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf** package but this is also opening in readable mode.

```
    $data = [
        'foo' => 'bar'
    ];
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.document', $data);
    return $pdf->stream('document.pdf');
```

Please suggest me if I need to configure any options to this code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a PDF with a fillable form with **dompdf** its **not** possible, because it's [not supported](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/1245), owner says:

> Dompdf supports rendering form fields as static content in the PDF but
>   **not** for rendering fillable forms.

Using **niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf** that uses **mpdf**, you can use *active forms* to archive a fillable PDF.

There's an extense [mpdf active forms example](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf-examples/blob/master/example57_new_mPDF_v5-3_active_forms.php#L125).

So, the blade html should look like:

```
<h2>Active Forms</h2>
<form action="formsubmit.php" method="post">
  <b>Input Text</b>
  <input type="text" size="90" name="inputfield" value="" title="The title attribute works like a tool-tip" />
</form>
```

Another possible solution would be use [laravel-fpdf](https://github.com/codedge/laravel-fpdf) package, that uses [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/). I think it's the best open-source PDF generator there is. You can easy import it, and you can select one dozen different pdf templates.

Comment: Hard does not mean it's not possible... I know that dompdf is newer but it's more dedicated for crafting pdf with html elements...